# It doesn't on/for/to me(preposition)

Tags: prepositions

Let's say there is a method/way that doesn't work in your case. Like this:

> spur-of-the-moment decisions do not work **for** me.

Or

> spur-of-the-moment decisions do not work **to** me.

Or

> spur-of-the-moment decisions do not work **on** me.

I find it difficult which of these is the correct one, cause they all make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples provided you would choose the first one.

> spur-of-the-moment decisions do not work **for** me.

Your usage of **for** would be fitting into the fourth definition for the word **for**.
[Link to Merriam-Webster Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)